# Errors making an array of stacks

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm working on a project in Java (I'm very new).

I'm trying to make two arrays that refer to the a similar set of objects (Indices 3-16) and respective 3 (Indices 0-2). I want the objects to be stacks (that I changed to be "Pile"s, which just have a method to report their lengths). Each of the "Pile" objects will be ready to accept "Piece" objects.

```
Pile<Piece>[] leftBoard = new Pile[16];
Pile<Piece>[] rightBoard = new Pile[16];
for (int i = 3; i < 16; i++){
    leftBoard[i] = new Pile<Piece>();
    rightBoard[i] = leftBoard[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
leftBoard[i] = new Pile<Piece>();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    rightBoard[i] = new Pile<Piece>();
}
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you changed stacks to piles? Does `Pile` actually mean `java.util.Stack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pile<Piece>[]` is an array of generics. [Due to type erasure in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), this is a Very Bad Thing™. Instead, try something like this:

```
// Initialize arrays.
ArrayList<Pile<Piece>> leftBoard = new ArrayList<Pile<Piece>>(16);
ArrayList<Pile<Piece>> rightBoard = new ArrayList<Pile<Piece>>(16);

// Fill arrays so we can use the "set" method.
leftBoard.add(Collections.<Pile<Piece>>nCopies(null));
rightBoard.add(Collections.<Pile<Piece>>nCopies(null));

// Store values.
for (int i = 3; i < 16; i++){
    Pile<Piece> thisPiece = new Pile<Piece>();
    leftBoard.set(i, thisPiece);
    rightBoard.set(i, thisPiece);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    leftBoard.set(i, new Pile<Piece>());
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     rightBoard.set(i, new Pile<Piece>());
}
```

`ArrayList` is also nicer because it's dynamically resizable (among many other things).

Quick rundown: if you have `String[] array` and `ArrayList list, then:

- `array[i]` is the same as `list.get(i)`
- `array[i] = var` is the same as `list.set(i, var)`
- You can add elements to the end with `list.add(var)`
- You can remove elements from anywhere with `list.remove(index)` or `list.remove(var)`
- For more, see the [`ArrayList` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [Java Tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

---

**EDIT**: On the topic of unmodifiable lists:

```
List<MyObject> l = Collections.unmodifiableList(myList);
l.get(0);             // valid as long as element exists
l.get(0).foo();       // valid
l.get(0).setFoo(bar); // valid
l.remove(foo);        // INVALID
l.add(foo);           // INVALID
```

So you can manipulate the objects *inside* the list but can't modify their *position* in the list or the contents of the list itself. Imagine a prison on lockdown - nobody in or out, but you can still talk to the prisoners.

If you want the `Pile`s to remain where they are but be able to move the `Piece`s, an unmodifiable list sounds good to me. As long as you have a method like `somePile.setPiece(somePiece)`, this should work fine.

Comment: How should I edit the
    leftBoard[i] = new Pile<Piece>(); parts?

Comment: By the way, you don't have to instantiate with `new ArrayList<Pile<Pieces>>(16)`; the size is optional, but if you know it it gives slightly better performance

Comment: Okay, that's perfect, thank you! It shouldn't be of variable size though for what I want. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. Finally, if you want an unmodifiable list (you can still modify the elements themselves, but can't add/remove/set/etc.) you can use `Collections.unmodifiableList(leftBoard)`.

Comment: I want to be able to move around the Piece objects, but not the Piles, they should be staying in place.